# What is the process name of Metricbeat? ( To stop the Metricbeat)

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, metricbeat, elastic-cloud

I'm trying out Elastic cloud. I've downloaded **Metricbeat- System metrics (Windows version)** and set it up on my local computer. I configured it so that I can see my local computer's memory, cpu, disk space, etc on my dashboard in Kibana on Cloud (Elastic Cloud).

I rebooted my local computer and expected Kibana not to get any more metric data from my local computer through Metricbeat. However, it is still getting data from my computer. **1) I want to know the name of the Metricbeat process.**   (I can't find it :( )

2) **I want to know how to stop Metricbeat on my local machine.** (If every time when I reboot my system, it also comes back up.  Killing the process wouldn't work in this case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved it.

I opened a taskmgr in Windows. And I found the process.

[image]

> The name of Metricbeat process is **metricbeat.exe**.

I killed the process, but it seems to run automatically when I restart my computer.

I went into the folder where I downloaded and installed Metricbeat.

[image]

Run PowerShell as administrator. And type **`.\uninstall-service-metricbeat.ps1`** to uninstall it.

[image]

Finally, in **Kibana**, from the moment when you uninstalled **Metricbeat**, it won't show any more data.

[image]